# Highcharts align plot points to start at y-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have tried everything I can to get the chart to start from the absolute left side of the chart (offsets, minPadding, startOnTick, etc.). No matter what I do I can't get it to start from the very far side. Here is picture examples:
[image]

Here is a code example im JsFiddle where you can try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/agrublev/VDVpu/3/

and here is some of the code:

```
chart: {
        type: 'area',
        height: '175'
    },
    legend: false,
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                click: function (e) {
                    location.href = e.point.options.url;
                }
            },
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: [0, 0, 0, 300],
                stops: [
                    [0, 'rgba(201,241,217,0)'],
                    [1, 'rgba(201, 241, 217,1)']
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['04/17', '04/17', '04/17', '04/18', '04/19', '04/19', '04/20', '04/20', '04/21', '04/21'],
        labels: {
            align: "left"
        },tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        startOnTick: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: false
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '$' + (this.value).formatMoney(0);
            },
            y: 15
        },
        alternateGridColor: '#f4f8f9',
        gridLineColor: '#c4dce2' 
    },
```

Would highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use categorized xAxis, try to use or linear, or datetime, with labelformatter.
Example:

```
xAxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function(){
       return names[this.value];
    }
  }
}
```

where `names` is array of categories. See: http://jsfiddle.net/9tpao7Lf/

Comment: Sure, see new jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of category series go for a date time series like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hAPa8/)

I've changed your jsfiddle you can check at http://jsfiddle.net/VDVpu/4/

```
xAxis:{
 type:'datetime',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want change the type of xAxis one possible solution is use min & max in xAxis options.

For referance check following jsfiddle code
http://jsfiddle.net/zdMTy/58/

```
    var categories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'];
    xAxis: {
          categories: categories,
          min: 0.5,
          max:categories.length - 1.5
    }
```