# Graphics start from axis + grid line

Tags: javascript, graphics, highcharts

I'm working on customization highcharts and i had some problem with http://jsfiddle.net/gF4x2/ this graphic

```
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
```

I think, some issue are easy, some not. Maybe someone encounter with the same problems and have resolved it.

1. Need that graphics start from y and x axis, now they are have padding and i dont know how to remove it.
2. I need to create some sort of this grid, but on my graphics i couldn't. i even dont know in what side i should look to get this. Maybe some one know decision or can give advice what i should do?

[image: Chart grid]

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't work for me.

Comment: hmm, all work fine on my computer, do you have some error messages?

Comment: Got it working by selecting 'OnDomready'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help a bit with the grid. You can use these options in your x-axis:

```
 gridLineWidth:1,
    plotBands:[
        {color:'lightgrey',from:0,to:3},
        {color:'lightgrey',from:9,to:11}
   ],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YabxW/

I've looked at this a bit more, and you can get closer to what you want using plotBands and the help that Ivan Chau has suggested. However, I would consider plotting this as two charts instead of one, as it's very hard to get exactly what you want in one chart.

Comment: I want to add a grid on top chart and bottom chart. I want that get these charts look like the picture.

Comment: About padding, i want that graphic starts from y-axis
[Want and have](http://d.pr/i/sRbX)

Answer (score 2):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DdFEB/

---

- **Align first data point to the left of the axis**

**Avoid** categorized x axis.

```
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
```

Use specific label formatter instead.

```
var xCategories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

Under `xAxis`:

```
    labels: {
        y: 25,
        formatter: function() {
            return xCategories[this.value];
        }
    },
```

Under `xAxis`: Use [`startOnTick`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.startOnTick) with [`maxPadding`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.maxPadding)

```
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0
```

Related questions:
[Put highchart on the very start of the graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281589/put-highchart-on-the-very-start-of-the-graphic)
[Highcharts align plot points to start at y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450069/highcharts-align-plot-points-to-start-at-y-axis?rq=1)
[highcharts start from hinges base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18052324/highcharts-start-from-hinges-base?rq=1)

- **Adding grid line**

Under `xAxis`:

```
    gridLineWidth: 0.5,
    gridLineColor: '#C0C0C0'
```

---

For this question: As the top chart and bottom chart mixed together, it is rather difficult to put the labels (e.g. Jan, Feb, etc...) in between the charts. Though it might be possible to do that.

You can see the effect by removing the following lines.

Under `xAxis`:

```
        top: -143,
```

Comment: almost what I want, but seems little bugs here, categories cut, any suggestion how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Do you mean the missing Feb labels when scaling the window?

Comment: There are several options: 1) Set x under `labels` to offset them but Dec needs special care 2) Set `showFirstLabel` and `showLastLabel` to false to hide 'Jan' and 'Dec'

Comment: Maybe you could adjust to `margin: [0, 20, 0, 0],` under `chart` to show Dec.